# how to change background color of paginator in angular-6-datatable

Tags: html, css, angular, datatables, angular6

So I'm using `angular-6-datatable` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable) in my project. But I can't seem to change the background color of the paginator. It looks like this:

[image]

I tried in-line styling even with !important but it still won't change.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

add your paginator css inside `:host /deep/` as shown below:

```
:host /deep/ {
 /*paginator style goes here*/
}
```

or

```
::ng-deep {
 /*paginator style goes here*/
}
```

Comment: just tried it but it doesn't seem to do anything? and what is `deep` here?

Comment: have you tried ::ng-deep ? ::ng-deep worked for me can you try and let me know?

Comment: tried it just now, and it works but instead of the active page number being colored (which is 1), page number 2 is colored

Comment: You need to add color to active number only there should be class active check and apply css to that class only or can you share your code here?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set color on page 1 then you just have to assign a dynamic class.

```
<div class="pagination" [ngClass]={'active':pageIndex == 1}>
    <!-- pagination stuff hear...  -->
</div>
```

**In .ts file**

```
pageIndex : any = '1';  // You have to update this when pagination value update , This way : pageIndex ++;
```

**In scss file**

```
:host ::ng-deep .pagination .active{
    background:red;
}
```